# Why a global temporary table is deleted on my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, session, temp-tables, session-timeout

We use global temporary tables in our program, written in C++ using ATL as a DB interface. Sessions are established with the SQL OLE DB provider.

This global temporary tables are held for a long time, maybe for the complete time of a session. Such temporary tables are explicitly deleted by us, when the specific action/activity ends. So we always clean up the tables.

Now we see an effect on people that are using a slow or unstable VPN connection that the global temporary is deleted. A query that should read some content returns an error

> ##tblTemp... is not a valid object name

For me it is an indicator that SQL Server terminated the session.

But how can it be? Our program has internal functions that access the server at least every 5 minutes (even if the user is inactive). Usually the SQL Server is accessed much more frequently. But the program may be minimized in the background.

What timeout is responsible that SQL Server terminates a session and deletes the temporary tables?

I see the `Remote Query Timeout` in the server settings. But this seams to be wrong for me, because we have no open query here... also the queries to the table are real simple. Insert an record, delete an record.

Questions:

1. Where do I find the settings for this session timeout?
2. Is there a way for the client to find out that the session got terminated? Strange for me the SQL query itself was transferred to SQL Server and finally failed because the temporary table did no longer exist. We got other error on the client.
3. Is there a way to protocol this on the server?

**EDIT:**

Here more details how we work with this tables.

- The tables are created in my main thread. This thread has a SQL session that is created at start of the program and ends with the program end.
- Other threads use the temporary tables. We pass the names through it.

So due to the fact that the creating SQL session is still alive and doesn't show an error when executing a statement that uses the temporary table, it tells me that the session is still alive. But my problem is the object seams to be deleted.

**Again: We only have this problem on machines with a slow / bad VPN connection to the server!**

Comment: It sounds like a global session-scoped object is not what you need, just create your table as tempdb.dbo.table directly, it will remain until your app drops it or server restarts.

Comment: Sounds like, if I am honest, what they actually need isn't something that's temporary at all, and they should be storing the data in a permanent table in a user database (and l the same table, not many tables), and if they want that data gone after they are finished with it, `DELETE` it.

Comment: It is temporary for the main session! Also it are small amounts of data, and the access should be memory buffered... all this is what a global temporary table provides. 
And I don't need DDL rights for the temp tables. datawriter  is enough.

Comment: *the access should be memory buffered* this is true of any table, once the data is read it remain in the buffer cache; if you're assuming a ##table is not written to disk, that's not true.

Comment: No. I don't assume that the tables are not written to disk... Thanks for your comments, but say don't shed light into my problem.

Comment: What would be the issue with just creating a user table either in tempdb or a user database and using it for the temporary/intermediate data as necessary, just deleting the data when it's no longer required. Is there a problem that using a global temporary table instead fixes?

Comment: @stu: Yes this would be a solution but it isn't an answer to what I asked for. The documentation tells me that this error shouldn't happen. And again: in 5000 installations we have no such problems. Except a view errors at 2 customers...

Comment: If the connection gets broken at any point then the session is closed, which means the tables will get deleted. It really sounds like you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Sure. But the session isn't closed. I don't get such a message. I get an error about a syntactical problem using the current session. If the session would be dead the message would be a different one. Any usage of any SQL statement would fail.
Also may software never retries if a session is terminated.
I expect that a session will last on if once created. Still my question: Why can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

To quote the manual:

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them. The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table when the creating session ended.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables)

So it's not about the *server* being accessed every few minutes, but the specific *object* being referenced.

If the session that created the global temporary table is ended (e.g. a timeout) and nothing else is *actively* referencing the same table, it is dropped!

Comment: I think you need to be sure of what you mean by "using them". If there is not an _active, open transaction_ involving that table then it is no longer "in use".

Comment: Sorry. Deleted my comment. Need to verify something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I rechecked this in detail. I added new comment to my question. The table should exist, because it is created in my main thread and so in my main session that still persists...